# simple 3-2-1 countdown in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

i'm trying to create a simple 3-2-1 counter. i would like to display the 3, 2, and 1, as well as run a function at the end of the countdown. i've tried a couple things to no avail:

```
$("#count_num").delay(1000).queue(function() {
        $(this).html("2")
        });
$("#count_num").delay(1000).queue(function() {
        $(this).html("1")
        });
```

and:

```
$("#count_num").delay(1000).queue(function() {
        $(this).html("2").delay(1000).queue(function() {
        $(this).html("1")
        });
        });
```

in these cases, it does get to 2 but never to 1. i also installed the doTimeout plugin (http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/) and tried this:

```
$.doTimeout( 1000, function(){
        $("#count_num").html("2");
        });
$.doTimeout( 1000, function(){
        $("#count_num").html("1");
        });
```

and:

```
var count=3;
        $.doTimeout( 1000, function(){
        if ( count==1 ) {
        // do something finally
        return false;
        }
        $("#count_num").html(count);
        count--;
        return true;
        });
```

what am i doing wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function endCountdown() {
  // logic to finish the countdown here
}

function handleTimer() {
  if(count === 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    endCountdown();
  } else {
    $('#count_num').html(count);
    count--;
  }
}

var count = 3;
var timer = setInterval(function() { handleTimer(count); }, 1000);
```

Doesn't use jQuery as much, but should work fine.

Comment: thanks for your response. i tried this, but it's not working. i added an alert here: "else {
    $('#count_num').html(count);
    count--;
 alert(count);
  }" . It goes to 2 but then keeps repeating 2 (never gets to 1).

Comment: Sorry, I gave `handleTimer` a parameter but it shouldn't have one. Try it now (updated answer).

Answer (score 3):

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
$("#count_num").html(function(i,html){
   if(parseInt(html)>0)
   {
   return parseInt(html)-1;
   }
   else
   {
   clearTimeout(timer);
   return "KO!!";
   }
 });

},1000);
```

Here is an [**example **](http://jsfiddle.net/eYjDk/2/)

Comment: This works but then dosen't stop at 0 it simply goes into minus -1, -2 etc, how can this be stopped at 0?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a plugin for this. With JavaScript you can do:

```
var count = 4;
function anim() {
    if (count > 0) {
        console.log(count);
        count--;
        setTimeout(anim, 700);
    }
    else {
        alert('end of counting')
    }
}
anim();
```

This will countdown from 4 then execute a function when count reaches 0.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/GSWRW/

Answer (score 2):

I've made a little jquery plugin that does exactly what you desire:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/countTo

https://github.com/bartrail/jQuery.countTo